# 'Can only be used in preamble' Error when using \input for a chapter

Tags: chapters, input, input-encodings, report, arara

It's my first post here; hopefully I'm not butchering how I'm supposed to post this.  I'm working in the Report class using Arara, trying to use \input to import a chapter.

```
% arara: pdflatex % arara: bibtex % arara: pdflatex % arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Basic Notions}
\input{chapters/ch1}

\end{document}
```

I then receive this error.  The path for the file is correct.

```
Chapter 1.
(C:\Users\Minks\Desktop\Bingo\chapters/ch1.tex

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 \documentclass
                  [12pt, twoside]{report}
?
```

Does anyone know what might be happening?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome! You have `\documentclass` in `ch1.tex`.  That won't work. Either load a package which will get rid of it or remove it. `\input{}` is just like putting the contents of the file there. So just as you can't have two `\documentclass` in one file, you can't have one in one file and one in a file you `\input`.

Comment: Off-topic: It is really not recommended to use the BibTeX backend with Biblatex now. Can you not use Biber instead?

Comment: You need to look into the [`combine`](//ctan.org/pkg/combine) or [`standalone`](//ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class/package.

Comment: Yup, that worked!  Thanks!  I might mess with the bibliography stuff if it stops working again, but that's the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: @Werner Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely combine separate documents into a single one, but one of the main requirements for using `\input` (and `\include`) is that the sub-documents are void of any preamble-specific commands.

For example, if you have `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% main preamble stuff
\begin{document}
\input{subfile}
\end{document}
```

your `subfile.tex` cannot include something like

```
\documentclass{article}
% sub-file preamble stuff
\begin{document}
\section{Some section}
Some text
\end{document}
```

One would consider `subfile.tex` to be completely "stand-alone" from `main.tex` in the sense that you can compile `subfile.tex` and receive an output document. In order to incorporate such a stand-alone file into another, you'll have to use special packages that ensures content within the sub-file preamble is ignored (including the use of the `document` environment). For this, packages like [`combine`](//ctan.org/pkg/combine) and [`standalone`](//ctan.org/pkg/standalone) comes to mind. There are others as well, as discussed on the [CTAN Topic of Subdocs](//ctan.org/topic/subdocs).

---

Of course, if the construction of the files can be controlled, just remove all the preamble (and `document` environment) stuff from `subfile.tex` so it resembles only

```
\section{Some section}
Some text
```

Then using `\include` or `\input` would work as expected (and without problem).